# How to use SLAM generated map to navigate my robot to the destination?

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, differential-drive

I am trying to understand various SLAM algorithms.

In my case, I need my robot to start from point A and reach point B with maximum accuracy as well as precision for all the cases.
[image]

Note that, as the pic below shows, there are'nt walls around for the conventional SLAM methods to vouch for. The square signifies a reference object ( a table for instance). The pic shows a top-view of the cases. I am aware that either of the cases (I, II or III) will need different SLAM instances, each with its own map.

Once I have the map, maybe using [ORB SLAM 2](https://github.com/Jiankai-Sun/ORB_SLAM2_Enhanced). How does one use the map to control the motors of the robot (can be tank bot) such that the map is utilized to get from A to B ?

Comment: If that is the full environment that you are planning in, with no other features in it, or at least a known initial position, an RF or IR beacon or something to help with the location, slam will not work, as there is no way to tell, by sensor readings alone on which side of the block you are.

Comment: The point A is well known, as it is the starting point (can be referenced as the origin). B is adjacent to the right of square (table actually).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a map, you need to use a planning algorithm to get the robot from point A to point B. I'd reccomend reading up on [RRT algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly-exploring_random_tree)

How to go from point A to point B is mostly independent of how you calculate the map and how you position yourself in the map.

Comment: This helps; could you also share an example of how __some__ SLAM technique could help the robot navigate from A to B, __specific__ to my case ?

Comment: What do you think is specific to your case that is different from SLAM in general? You have not defined what sensors you're using, what kind of robot, what any of the symbols in your picture represent even?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing it out. I have added more info.